# Pages not in correct order when printing

Tags: 20.04, printing, hp

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed and an HP Deskjet 2540. Both devices communicate over WIFI.
When I try to print 4 pages on one side, the page order is **not** correct (regardless of printing from Okular, Evince, Firefox).

I want my pages to be in the following format:

1 --> 2

3 --> 4,

and the page should be in landscape mode.

1, 2, 3 and refer to the page numbers. However, when I directly print from Firefox, for instance (with the setting 4 pages per side & orientation in landscape), I get other formats
(like 3 --> 4, 2 --> 1).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Open the print dialog. This can normally be done through Print in the menu or using the Ctrl+P keyboard shortcut.

Click the Properties… button

In the Orientation drop-down list, make sure that Landscape is selected.

In the Duplex drop-down list, select Short Edge.

Click OK to go back to the print dialog.

Under Range and Copies, choose Pages.

Type the numbers of the pages in this order (n is the total number of pages, and a multiple of 4):

n, 1, 2, n-1, n-2, 3, 4, n-3, n-4, 5, 6, n-5, n-6, 7, 8, n-7, n-8, 9, 10, n-9, n-10, 11, 12, n-11…

```
Examples:

    4 page booklet: Type 4,1,2,3

    8 page booklet: Type 8,1,2,7,6,3,4,5

    20 page booklet: Type 20,1,2,19,18,3,4,17,16,5,6,15,14,7,8,13,12,9,10,11

Choose the Page Layout tab.

Under Layout, select Brochure.

Under Page Sides, in the Include drop-down list, select All pages.

Click Print.
```

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/printing-booklet-duplex.html.en)